# SignalR IUserIdProvider not invoked for userid and connectionid mapping

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am sending userid from javascript while i am making request to signalr as follows:

```
 var userId = "1";
    var connection = $.hubConnection("/signalr", { useDefaultPath: false });
    var notificationsHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('NotificationsHub');
    connection.qs = "userId=" + userId;
    notificationsHubProxy.on('notify', function (notifications) {
        notifyAll(notifications);
    });
    connection.start()
        .done(function() {
            notificationsHubProxy.invoke('getNotifications', "1,2,3");
        })
        .fail(function(reason) {
            alert('signalr error');
        });
```

Here is the class for implementing IUserIdProvider that retrieves querystring and returns as userId, i debugged and this class and GetUserId method was not invoked by the framework.

```
 public class RealTimeNotificationsUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
{
    public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
    {
      return  request.QueryString["userId"];
    }
}
```

Here is my startup class for hooking up IUserId provider with signalR configuration:

```
      var userIdProvider = new RealTimeNotificationsUserIdProvider();
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => userIdProvider);
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
       {
           var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
           {            
                EnableDetailedErrors  = true,
                Resolver = dependencyResolver,
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = false
           };
           map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
       });
```

Now, when i try to send notification to a particular User by accessing Clients.User(userId) its not working:

```
        var userId = "1";
        Clients.User(userId).notify("test");
```

what am i missing? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks like it should work. The only thing that looks suspicious is that you are registering your `IUserIdProvider` with `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver`, but then you have `Resolver = dependencyResolver` in your HubConfiguration.

There is no other reference to `dependencyResolver` anywhere else in your question. If you were to leave out `Resolver = dependencyResolver`, SignalR would use `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver` by default.

Answer (score 0):

hier is what I did to solve this problem, form me request.QueryString["userId"] did not return user id that is why it did not work, I change your code like below and it does work I tested t on my project:

```
   using using System.Web;

  public class RealTimeNotificationsUserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
  {
   public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
   {
      return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()
   }
 }
```

- remove  var userIdProvider = new RealTimeNotificationsUserIdProvider() and write it like below:

  ```
   ConfigureAuth(app);
   GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () =>  new RealTimeNotificationsUserIdProvider());
          app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
          {            
          EnableDetailedErrors  = true,                
          EnableJavaScriptProxies = false
           };
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
         });
  ```